# Printing network properties of nodes with igraph for R

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I'm doing SNA with the igraph R package and need to save some network properties of the nodes along with each node's id to a file for further analysis. That is,  a document with the first column representing a node id and the other columns its properties. 
I'm ok with centrality measures but other igraph functions like transitivity for example, return only a vector with the computed network properties as in

```
transitivity(graph,type=c("local"))

[1] 0.4285714 0.3976608 0.5454545 0.7142857 0.3928571 0.4640523
[7] 0.5620915 0.6095238 0.3571429 0.4743590 0.3416667 0.6023392
[13] 0.6000000 0.5228758 0.4771242 0.4835165 0.3246753 0.5000000
[19] 0.3636364 0.5777778 0.3571429 0.4487179 0.5238095 0.4857143
```

What I would like to do is to be able to add transitivity to the following data frame of centrality measures:

```
metrics <- data.frame(
  deg=degree(graph)
  bet=betweenness(graph)
  clo=closeness(graph)
  eig=evcent(graph)$vector
)
```

which returns:

```
    deg        bet        clos       eig
001   7  8.6046215 0.009523810 0.1697311
002  19 48.2885279 0.012500000 0.7012156
003  12 10.5285962 0.011111111 0.4280625
004  15  8.6161170 0.011363636 0.7729130
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I s the question how to add a vector to a data.frame? Use `cbind`

Comment: Well, I didn't quite know how to phrase my question properly and Scott's solution seems to work just fine. I guess I could have used cbind as well but maybe node ids order would have not been kept? Anyway, thanks for your comment @agstudy, it made me think of a possible solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the function to your `data.frame`:

```
metrics <- data.frame(
  deg=degree(graph),
  bet=betweenness(graph),
  clo=closeness(graph),
  eig=evcent(graph)$vector,
  tra=transitivity(graph,type=c("local"))
)
```

Comment: Cheers Scott. So, if I understand well, all node ids are kept in the same order for all the functions applied to the graph?

Comment: presumably yes, especially since the functions don't return what node each measure belongs to

Answer (score 0):

You can add V(graph)$name to your data frame to get the ids associated with the measures.

```
 metrics <- data.frame(
   id = V(graph)$name
   deg=degree(graph),
   bet=betweenness(graph),
   clo=closeness(graph),
   eig=evcent(graph)$vector,
   tra=transitivity(graph,type=c("local"))
 )
```